# Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is unbounded for $x\in(-1,1)$

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that $f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is unbounded for $x\in(-1,1)$; so I must prove that for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$ is $f(x) > M$ for $x\in(-1,1)$.

With the definition of limit, since
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x)=\lim_{x \to -1^+} f(x)=\infty$$
For all $M>0$ exists $\delta_M>0$ such that if (for instance) $1-\delta_M<x<1$ then $f(x)>M$, so since $M>0$ is arbitrary the definition of unbounded function is satisfied; the doubt is that I don't know how to work with the $x$ interval for which that is true, I mean that I know from the definition of limit that when $1-\delta_M < x <1$ it is $f(x)>M$ but how do I make this rigorous?

I was thinking something like this: since $f$ is continuous in $(-1,1)$, for the Weierstrass theorem $f$ has maximum and minimum (so is bounded) in every interval of the kind $[-1+t,1-t]$ for $t>0$; so if I choose $\delta_M<t$ I can conclude that $f$ is unbounded because it is greater than $M$ for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$ in the interval $[1-\delta_M,1) \subset [1-t,1)$. Is this correct?

However if this is correct I have another doubt: how do I prove that $[-1+t,1-t]$ is limited and closed? I know it is trivial, but I've never done this before.

Another attempt is by contradiction: suppose that $f$ is bounded, then exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$; so we have
$$0<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \leq C \Leftrightarrow0<1\leq C\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Taking the limit for $x \to1^-$ both sides we have that
$$0\leq \lim_{x \to 1^-} 1 \leq \lim_{x \to 1^-} C\sqrt{1-x^2}=0$$
So by comparison we have
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} 1=0$$
Which is a contradiction. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Ouch, you make this million times too complicated, I am afraid.

Comment: Why are you bothering with limits? For any $M>0$, just pick an appropriate value of $x$ such that $f(x)>M$. You can be totally explicit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I think that too :( any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}>M\iff |x|>\sqrt{1-\frac1{M^2}}.$$

This inequation has solutions in $(-1,1)$ for all $M$ ($\ne0$).

Comment: Thanks. One last thing: when you say that the inequality has solutions in $(-1,1)$ for all $M\ne0$ is because $|x|>\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{M^2}}\Leftrightarrow x>\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{M^2}} \lor x<-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{M^2}}$ and it is $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{M^2}}<1$ and $-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{M^2}}>-1$ for all $M\in\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ so there always are $x$ that satisfy those inequalities simultaneously (i.e. those $x$ are $x\in\left(-1,-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{M^2}}\right) \cup \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{M^2}},1\right)$).

Comment: @ZaWarudo: note that there is no need to have solutions on both sides for the function to be unbounded. What matters is that for any $M$ there is at least one $x$.

Comment: Yes, I've said that because I was referring to the inequality part. It's enough to exhibit an $x$ that makes that inequality true and the ones that satisfy the inequality are the ones in the union of intervals that I've written. Thanks again for your kindness!

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need all that? Let $M>1$. Then from
$$
M=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
we get
$$
x^2=1-\frac{1}{M^2}
$$
and this equation has a solution in the interval $(-1,1)$ because $0<1/M^2<1$.

---

If you already know that $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=\infty$ you need nothing more to show that the function is upper unbounded. Indeed, if it were bounded by $K$, then you cannot find (left) neighborhoods of $1$ such that $f(x)>K$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is all clear except when you say "let $M>1$"; why can we suppose that? Don't we lose generality since we must prove the statement for all $M$? Maybe it is general because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \geq 1$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$, so it is enough to prove the statement for $M>1$. Is because of that?

Comment: @ZaWarudo I can't see where's the problem. Any value is good in order to show that the function is unbounded. Since you *know* the function is continuous, takes on the value $1$ at $0$ and is unbounded, solving the equality $f(x)=M$ for $M>1$ is quite natural.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is an even function, it suffices to consider $x \in [0,1).$

Assume $(1-x^2)^{1/2} <M (>0)$, real, for all $x \in [0,1)$.

Then $1/M^2 < 1-x^2$;

Set $y_n:=x_n^2=1-1/n$;

$1/M^2 < 1/n$, for large enough $n$ a contradiction.